# How is it possible to make a Triangle Badge in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a Triangle Badge in Flutter, the library https://github.com/yako-dev/flutter_badges didn't get it.

The goal is to make something like this:

[image]

How is it possible?

I tried to extend the library flutter_badges, but there are too many problems.

Comment: Instead of editing your post, add an answer to your question and validate it

Comment: It's now implemented in the library. https://github.com/yako-dev/flutter_badges/issues/106